# elasticsearch 5.0 aborted snapshot still preventing deletion of indices

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot, elasticsearch-5

Elasticsearch prevents deletion of an index while it is being snapshotted. This is fine and when I identified a long running snapshot (since February) that still had shards in the 'STARTING' status I cancelled it via a DELETE. This changed the snapshot task's status to 'ABORTED' although when I subsequently attempted to delete an index it was previously 'snapshotting' it still denied the request.

How can I delete the affected indices?